# Boot process stuck at "Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service"

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I have been using Ubuntu 17.10 for the past 4 months without any problems.  Today I rebooted my laptop and it has started to get stuck at "Started GNOME Display Manager.  Dispatcher Service" when booting.

I have not made any major changes or updates recently.  I also can not access another tty using ctrl + alt + F1,F2

I have recorded a video of what happens. I have googled to try and find a solution but unable to find anything specific.

Has anyone experienced this?  Any help would be appreciated.

https://youtu.be/5WyQxAfRz1A

Thanks!